# Convert K style Numbers to int / long

Tags: java, php, android

I have some text like this:

title
link (http//a.com/......)
username (id -> @......)
members

any user can send this data for app I want to detect members and convert to `int` or `long`

for example

```
100K -> 100000
5.8 -> 5800
2.3k -> 2300
20 k -> 20000
200 -> 200
500 -> 500
8000 -> 8000
```

first I should find that text that is includes "0-9" and "." and "k" and "m" character only before start convertion.

php:

```
function getOrginalNumber($mystring)
{
    $mystring = strtolower($mystring);
    $pos1 = stripos($mystring, ".");
    $pos2 = stripos($mystring, "k");
    if ($pos1 == 0 && $pos2 == 0) {
    } else if ($pos1 == 0 && $pos2 > 0) {
        $mystring = str_replace("k", "000", $mystring);
    } else if ($pos1 > 0 && $pos2 == 0) {
        $mystring = str_replace(".", "", $mystring);
    } else if ($pos1 > 0 && $pos2 > 0) {
        $mystring = str_replace(".", "", $mystring);
        if (strlen($mystring) - 1 == 1) {
            $mystring = str_replace("k", "000", $mystring);
        } else if (strlen($mystring) - 1 == 2) {
            $mystring = str_replace("k", "00", $mystring);
        }
    }
    return $mystring;
}

function isNumber($string)
{
    $s = convert_to_en_number($string);
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9k.]+$/', $s)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and use:

```
 foreach ($fields as &$value) {
        if (isNumber($value)) {
            $value = getOrginalNumber($value);
        }
    }
```

But it not work correctly some times.

I need `java` code.

Comment: @Nigel i need java code not php

Comment: @Nigel Ren remove duplicate please it not work for me

Comment: If you have tried to write some code (in Java) and having issues with it, then *please ask a new question* with the relevant code and the issue your having with it.